# wxWidgets problem - libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.1.a: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gtk, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile a program that uses wxWidgets. When I run `"make"`, it is returned to me :

```
Building target using GCC compiler: sources/geometry-manager.cpp
g++ -g -c sources/geometry-manager.cpp -std=c++17 -w -c -rdynamic -W `wx-config --cxxflags --libs --gl-libs` `geos-config --cflags` -lgeos -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm -lGLEW  -o builded/geometry-manager.o `pkg-config --libs geographiclib`
g++: error: /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.1.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:37: builded/geometry-manager.o] Erro 1
```

I'm using the Ubuntu 20.04 (Linux 5.8.0-55-generic).

`wx-config --version-full` returns `3.1.5.0`

`wx-config --selected-config` returns `gtk3-unicode-static-3.1`

`libgtk-3-dev` is installed

The program is compiled on other computers. I believe I installed some dependency.incorrectly

The file libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.1.a does not exist on my file system. But I couldn't find the download file.

thank you so much

`wx-config --cxxflags --libs std,gl` returns:

```
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-static-3.1 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_qa-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_html-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.a -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lX11 -lSM -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lXtst -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lwxtiff-3.1 -lwxjpeg-3.1 -lwxregexu-3.1 -lwxscintilla-3.1 -lexpat -lpng -lz -ldl -lm
```

`libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev` is already the newest version (3.0.4+dfsg-15build1).

Success: I reinstalled wxWidgets. Now openGL was identified at installation and it worked.

Comment: @ChristianPastro, what is the original wx version it was built with? What is the result of `wx-config --cxxflags --libs std,gl`?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev` Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have built wxWidgets yourself, but when configuring it, configure didn't find the required OpenGL headers/libraries, so OpenGL support was disabled, as you can confirm by looking at `config.log` file it created. You will also find the details of why did this fail in the same file, but you probably just need to `apt install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev` (and rerun configure and `make && make install`, of course, to actually build and install the OpenGL part of wx).

You may also want to explicitly run configure with `--with-opengl` option, as in this case you will get an error, rather than the warning you get by default, if OpenGL libraries are not available.